# What exactly is the problem if React's click handler is a new function every time?

Tags: reactjs

Both of these forms returned from a component:

```
  <button onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}>
```

or

```
  <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
```

creates a new function each time. And it is said it is a problem.  But what exactly is a problem?

[The docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) says:

> The problem with this syntax is that a different callback is created each time the LoggingButton renders. In most cases, this is fine. However, if this callback is passed as a prop to lower components, those components might do an extra re-rendering.

But isn't it wrong concept?

1) First, this itself is a problem, even if it is not passed down to to a lower component. Because when this is rendered to a virtual DOM tree, it is compared to the previous virtual DOM tree, and seeing it is a different click handler, it needs to update the actual DOM -- either by changing the `onclick` attribute or by `removeEventListener()` and `addEventListener()` to change the handler.  Usually we don't want to update the actual DOM, as it is much more expensive than the virtual DOM.

2) Second, no matter it is passed down to lower components, the lower components will re-render anyway.  UNLESS if the lower components are PureComponent or are optimized by React.memo(). But if they are just Component, the lower components are re-rendered anyway.  So this conveys a wrong concept.  It can cause actual DOM update in lower components, but this is covered in (1) already, and is true regardless of whether it is passed down the lower components.

3) One possibility is that changing the event listener is not as costly as other actual DOM operations, so the concern is if the click handler is passed down to lower components and the components use a PureComponent or React.memo to not re-render when the props didn't change, and passing in a new handler will cause the lower components to re-render.  But this is the case only if lower components are not the regular Component.

So the actual problem is about needing to cause an update to the actual DOM.

And the word "re-render" above doesn't mean an update to actual DOM. "re-render" means making a virtual DOM tree, either by the `render()` of a class component, or by a function component returning React elements just like `render()`. (just to make sure we are talking about the same thing).

Comment: There are a lot of assumptions being made about internal implementation details of react. It could be that the built-in components just keep a ref on handlers and bind a handler once that just calls that. But it shouldn't really matter as re-rendering is far more expensive and should be avoided if not necessary. This has simply shown to be the biggest problem in benchmarks of huge react apps like the facebook site.

Comment: @trixn you mean if a new handler is created, React somehow "not follow order" and use an old handler? (because theoretically, if React follows order, it should really use a new handler.) So you are saying in the Facebook site, there are a lot of PureComponent, Reat.memo, or useMemo to avoid calling `render()` again. If that's the case, then it matters. Somehow I thought as it is stated, it sounds like a mis-concept and I want to set the record straight here: for lower Component children, it doesn't matter. It matters only if the lower children are "optimized"

Comment: I mean that it is not said that react really calls `addEventListener()` or something similar when a mounted built-in component receives a new handler. It might just update a reference with it that gets called when the actual event happens. Of course it always has to use a newly passed handler.

Comment: @trixn React can always use the same click handler, which is just a generic handler. Inside that handler, it could in turn call the "newly created handler" -- is that what you mean? I guess in that case, it can be less costly

Comment: Yes that sounds about like what I mean. So the overhead that is created by the built-in components when passing a new handler might me pretty low. But the main point is that re-rendering overhead is known to be one of the main performance killers from many benchmarks of huge apps. So it should be avoided in most cases, at least when involving components that you control. On the other hand often it simply doesn't matter for practical reasons which is why you should start optimizing when you actually know the non-memorized handler might cause performance problems in your own components.

Comment: But I agree that the docs could be a little more verbose about when exactly it is fine to ignore memorization.